# Attempting to fully understand Readln in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Ok, i just want to make sure i fully understand Readln in delphi, does it only read the line of code above it? for example

`Var name, surname: String;`

`Write('Enter your name:');`
 readln(name);

Does it only apply to the write('Enter your name:');

Thank you for any clarification!

Comment: Hint: take out the write statement and do a quick test..

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Readln in the documentation, and there is a code example at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/SystemReadln_(Delphi). The doc links are for XE4, but `ReadLn` hasn't changed much since Turbo Pascal days, so the docs are still correct. (Just to clarify: it was my vote to close the question, not @Sertac's. SO should not be used as a replacement for reading the documentation for basic information.)

Comment: Thank you, taking out the write statement helped me out alot. Thank you everyone for your answers, all were awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readln has nothing to do with "the line of code above it."  It reads data from an input source, and stores it into the file in question.  If all you give it is a variable, it will read from the keyboard.  If you also give it a file handle, it will read from that file instead.

Comment: So Just so im clear, it "reads" what the user puts in and then stores it into  variable?

Comment: @Sheep: Yes. It treats the variable you give it as a **var** parameter.